# Accessing Xml Parameters Efficiently in a Stored Procedure

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to optimize a stored procedure that relies on a few `XML` type parameters for variable input.  Analysis of the execution plan shows a high cost associated with accessing the data in these parameters.

Given:

```
DECLARE @FirstNameXML  XML;
```

In the format of

```
<FirstNames>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Name>Joe</Name>
</FirstNames>
```

There are a few operations I need to perform (assuming the parameter is non-null):

**Count of Names supplied**

```
SET @FirstNameCount = 
  (SELECT COUNT(FirstNameValues.Name.value('.','VARCHAR(50)'))
  FROM @FirstNameXML.nodes('/FirstNames/Name') 
  AS FirstNameValues(Name))
```

**If count = 1**

```
...
AND First_Name LIKE
  (SELECT TOP(1) FirstNameValues.Name.value('.','VARCHAR(50)') + '%'
  FROM @FirstNameXML.nodes('/FirstNames/Name') 
  AS FirstNameValues(Name))
...
```

**Else if count > 1**

```
...
AND First_Name IN
(SELECT FirstNameValues.Name.value('.','VARCHAR(50)')
  FROM @FirstNameXML.nodes('/FirstNames/Name') 
  AS FirstNameValues(Name))
...
```

I have tried a few optimizations:

**Changing the count query to**:

```
SET @FirstNameCount = 
  (SELECT CAST(CAST(@FirstNameXML.query('count(/FirstNames/Name)') 
    AS VARCHAR(10)) AS INT)
```

**Changing the count == 1 query to**:

```
...
AND First_Name LIKE
  (SELECT @FirstNameXML.value('(/FirstNames/Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') + '%')
...
```

Somehow the stored procedure runs even slower after the optimizations even though the changes seem to have reduced the cost in the execution plan.  This leaves me with a few questions:

1. **Am I misunderstanding the optimizations I've implemented?**
2. **Is there a more efficient way to go about this as a whole?** (XML parameter based querying)

Comment: Use the xml to populate a temporary table and then join to it, would have been the way I went.

Comment: @marc_s What exactly was the point of your edit?  You removed all of my attempts at adding emphasis (on keywords in the title and the actual questions I'm asking).

Comment: Too much emphasis isn't a good thing .. and I don't think titles here should be all with capitalized first letters - but that's just me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the rows from the XML to a table variable or a temporary table. Make sure there is an index on the Name column in the table variable/temp table. I also don't see the need to have different queries for when count is 1 or many. This way you will only parse your XML one time.

Note. The execution plan costs is not to be trusted when it comes to XML. Better to test with `set statistics time on` and measure the actual performance instead.

```
-- Test data
declare @FirstNameXML xml;
set @FirstNameXML = 
'<FirstNames>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Name>Joe</Name>
</FirstNames>'

-- Put your data in a table variable.
-- Have Name as a primary key and you will get an index
declare @T table
(
  Name varchar(50) primary key
)

-- Add rows from XML to @T
insert into @T(Name)
select distinct T.N.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from @FirstNameXML.nodes('FirstNames/Name') as T(N)

select *
from YourTable
where First_Name in (select Name from @T)
```